Mongoose CastErrror when pushing to an array field
In my application, I have a User model which contains the fields requests and followers, which both store an array of ObjectIds.
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    followers: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    ],
    requests: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    ]
})

I have a query which should push to the followers array, each of the id's in the current documents's requests field. Once this has been done, the requests should be then set to an empty array. Here is the query to try accomplish this:
   User.updateOne(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $push: { followers: { $each: "$requests" } }, $set: { requests: [] } }
    )

However, when running this code, I get the following error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "$requests" (type string) at path "followers" because of "BSONError"
Any idea why this is error is occuring, and are there any potential solutions I could use in order to perform this query correctly? Thanks.

In your updateOne when you use $requests, MongoDB interprests that as the String literal "$requests" - not the variable $requests.
If you want to use variables like that you need to adopt the Updates with Aggregation Pipeline approach using square brackts [] to define a pipeline of aggregation stages.
A simple example that would meet your desired needs would be to leverage the $concatArrays aggregation operator like so:
await User.updateOne({
  _id: req.user._id
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      followers: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$followers",
          "$requests"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      requests: []
    }
  }
])

See HERE for a working example using db.collection.update()

thanks for the answer. One question I have is that a requirement I have is that a user id cannot be inside the requests array and the followers  array at any given time. In the code above, before requests is set to an empty array, there will be common  user id's in both requests and followers arrays. Is there any way to accomplish this update so that when a ID is pushed to followers it is definitely removed from requests array? Thanks

"In MongoDB, a write operation on a single document is atomic.". Given you are updating a single document in a single updateOne method then the write will be done in one go. You won't have the same id in both arrays because the requests is being set to an empty array within the same operation.

Ok, so the requests and the followers array are being updated at the exact same time, and there is no order in which they are done in? e.g followers array being set first if its the first update condition, then the requests being set to an empty array given it's the second condition. This is irrelevant right?  Also if the requests are set to empty, how is the followers array updated as the requests have been set to an empty array in the same update? Thanks

So it's done in memory. Yes the followers is being set first from a logical perspective but before it's written back to disk both fields will have been updated at the same time.

Ah ok I think I understand, at the time when the document is actually updated, both fields are set at the same time, theoretically making it impossible for ‘followers’ and ‘requests’ to share any common elements. This is correct right ?

That's correct.
